# CSS Position Divs at the same increment no matter the size?

Tags: html, css

I am making a vertical (scroll down) RSS feed where images have different heights. Right now my div boxes fit accordingly to the content however boxes that are too large overlap the box underneath. I want to have a set measurement for the space in between each box. For example, one box might have a height of 500 pixels and another might have a height of 200, and the box under that might have a height of 150. I want the space in between the boxes to be the same.

```
#feedbox {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgb(5, 58, 130);
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 300px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 450px;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

I am also using jinja to dynamically create the images, if that affects anything:

```
{% for row in feed %}
            <div id='feedbox'>
                <h1>{{ row.title }}</h1>
                <p>{{ row.description }}</p>
                <a href={{ row.link }}>Read more</a>
                <p>{{ row.displayDate }}</p>
                <img style='width: 100%; max-width: 400px; max-height: 400px;' src={{ row.image }} alt='Image'>
            </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `margin-bottom` css of the container for each image to be the set amount of space that you'd like to have between them. Is the `#feedbox` element the container for the webpage or for the image? If it's the container for the webpage, also use a div, or something else as a container for each image to achieve this.